# Requery of subform does not activate conditional formatting and puts new record at the bottom

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a form with a 2-page tab control.

The first page has a subform with a button on the subform that's supposed to requery another subform that is on the second page.

```vb
Forms!myMainForm!mySubForm.Requery
```

The main form and its fields are used to create new records and the subform on the second page shows these records.

Here's a screenshot of page 1's subform and button:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f3L3.jpg

When the button is clicked, the subform on the second page shows any new record at the bottom of the list instead of being sorted in descending date/time order. Also the Funding Rate field does not seem to get its conditional formatting applied:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H2mT.jpg

I've been able to get the subform to display correctly if I also add some VBA to the button to switch to the second page of the tab, but I'd rather not do this.

Is it possible to requery a subform and have it display correctly when the user is ready to see it?

Answer (score 1):

Migrate froms Tabs to Navigation Control. Usual Tabs are preloaded and will increase the main form load time. On the other hand, Navigation control only loads the form when its opened. This eliminates your needs to manually re-query the second tab.

PS: I'm interested in something in your form, what is your best contact method?

Comment: You can email me if you like: matthew.richard.hall@gmail.com

Comment: Navigation control is not something I've ever used, so will have to do some reading up on it. Thanks for this suggestion though.

Comment: its very simple and elegant.. can sense you will greatly profit from navigation controls.

Answer (score 0):

```
Forms!myMainForm!mySubForm.Requery
```

This requeries the `mySubForm` control on `myMainForm`, but not the subform itself.

Try instead:

```
Forms!myMainForm!mySubForm.Form.Requery
```

(note: I'm not 100% sure this will solve the issue)

Comment: Hello again! Alas this requeried the form in the same way as before (new data showing, but subform not reordering and conditional formats not applied).